# AngularJS performance - too many watchers?

Tags: angularjs, performance, debugging

I'm trying to debug an AngularJS website to improve performance of the load time. At the moment the browser freezes for 1-2 seconds on the first load with no caching.

From reading various posts I learned that watchers are often the biggest problem for performance in AngularJS apps.

Here is a screenshot from batarang:

[image: batarang results]
But, how many is too many watchers?  7k~ is a lot, but is that too many?

When debugging in the Chrome console CPU profile, I have a hard time figuring out what calls h - k - z.onload and in general how to improve performance besides having less watchers:

[image: cpu profile results]

I know it's a broad question, but I'm looking for any performance tips for AngularJS.

Comment: Not sure, how to guess, without looking at code..? 1.5-2k+ watcher will degrade performance for sure, though you could go through [this article](http://bahmutov.calepin.co/improving-angular-web-app-performance-example.html), that might help you.

Answer (score 7):

Angular start to hit the performence wall when having more then 2000 watchers.

If you have 7K+ watchers in your app, it is due to bad design.

see here https://coderwall.com/p/d_aisq/speeding-up-angularjs-s-digest-loop
and here [How does data binding work in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/how-does-data-binding-work-in-angularjs)